# GNU C++ how to check when -std=c++0x is in effect?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++11

My system compiler (gcc42) works fine with the TR1 features that I want, but trying to support newer compiler versions other than the systems, trying to accessing TR1 headers an #error demanding the -std=c++0x option because of how it interfaces with library or some hub bub like that.

```
/usr/local/lib/gcc45/include/c++/bits/c++0x_warning.h:31:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
```

Having to supply an extra switch is no problem, to support GCC 4.4 and 4.5 under this system (FreeBSD), but obviously it changes the picture!

Using my system compiler (g++ 4.2 default dialect):

```
#include <tr1/foo>
using std::tr1::foo;
```

Using newer (4.5) versions of the compiler with -std=c++0x:

```
#include <foo>
using std::foo;
```

Is there anyway using the pre processor, that I can tell if g++ is running with C++0x features enabled?

**Something like this is what I'm looking for**:

```
#ifdef __CXX0X_MODE__
#endif
```

but I have not found anything in the manual or off the web.

At this rate, I'm starting to think that life would just be easier,  to use Boost as a dependency, and not worry about a new language standard arriving before TR4... hehe.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you compile with `-std=c++0x`, then `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` will be defined.

Comment: Till GCC adds in the new __cplusplus defined the most portable options would be to add '#if defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__) || __cplusplus >= 201103L'

Comment: Is the same for `-std=c++11` and GCC4.8.1?

Answer (score 83):

There seems, with gcc 4.4.4, to be only one predefined macro hinting that -std=c++0x is in effect:

```
#define __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ 1
```

I don't have access to gcc 4.5.0 , but you can check that one yourself:

```
[16:13:41 0 ~] $ g++ -E -dM -std=c++0x -x c++ /dev/null >b
[16:13:44 0 ~] $ g++ -E -dM -std=c++98 -x c++ /dev/null >a
[16:13:50 0 ~] $ diff -u a b
--- a   2010-06-02 16:13:50.200787591 +0200
+++ b   2010-06-02 16:13:44.456912378 +0200
@@ -20,6 +20,7 @@
 #define __linux 1
 #define __DEC32_EPSILON__ 1E-6DF
 #define __unix 1
+#define __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ 1
 #define __LDBL_MAX_EXP__ 16384
 #define __linux__ 1
 #define __SCHAR_MAX__ 127
```

For one-line command do,

```
g++ -E -dM -std=c++98 -x c++ /dev/null > std1 && g++ -E -dM -std=c++0x -x c++ /dev/null > std2 && diff -u std1 std2 | grep '[+|-]^*#define' && rm std1 std2
```

gives you something like:

```
+#define __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ 1
```

Comment: +1: “Give a man a fish; you have fed him for today.  Teach a man to fish; and you will not have to listen to his incessant whining about how hungry he is.” :)

Comment: You might have to listen to fish stories where `->|    |<-` is an inch.

Comment: You can use bash process substitution to avoid using `std1` and `std2`: `diff -u <(g++ -E -dM -std=c++98 -x c++ /dev/null) <(g++ -E -dM -std=c++0x -x c++ /dev/null)`

Answer (score 17):

Well, from [gcc-4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html) onwards you'll be able to check __cplusplus:

"G++ now sets the predefined macro __cplusplus to the correct value, 199711L for C++98/03, and 201103L for C++11"

This should be the correct, standard-compliant way to do it.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work for most gcc installed in the wild.

Comment: FWIW this comes from C++11 16.8/1.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, you're right that this feature is not specifically gcc but is C++ standard.  Unfortunately, because of some issue on one of gcc targets we couldn't define __cplusplus sensibly even for C++03/98.  I think the target was deprecated finally and we could move on.