# capture C++0x flag inside the program

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GNU C++ how to check when -std=c++0x is in effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958398/gnu-c-how-to-check-when-std-c0x-is-in-effect)

What I want to do is:

```
 #if defined(CPLUSPLUS_OXFLAG)
  //do something
 #else
  //do something else
 #endif
```

Now how can I capture -std=c++0x argument passed to the compiler(g++) to `define` my `CPLUSPLUS_OXFLAG` flag?

Comment: You could try something like `#if __cplusplus >= 201103L #define CPLUSPLUS_OXFLAG #endif`.

Comment: In standard C++0x, ["the macro __cplusplus will be set to a value that differs from (is greater than) the current 199711L"](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#0x). I'm not sure if the experimental C++0x GCC implementation will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) states that the preprocessor symbol `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` is defined when compiling with `-std=c++0x`.

Answer (score 2):

For GCC have a look at this:

**__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__**

This macro is defined when compiling a C++ source file with the option -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x. It indicates that some features likely to be included in C++0x are available. Note that these features are experimental, and may change or be removed in future versions of GCC.

Find the reference **[here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros)**.

Comment: thanks... +1 for the reference

Answer (score 1):

GCC defines `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` when `std=c++0x` is enabled.