# isblank() is not recognized

Tags: c++, char, ctype

It seems that the isblank() function of the cctype header does not recognized by the gcc compiler. I use code blocks and I get:

**error: 'isblank' was not declared in this scope**

I checked the gcc cctype header and found the following lines:

```
   81 #ifdef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
   82 
   83 #ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_CTYPE_TR1
   84 
   85 #undef isblank
   86 
   87 namespace std
   88 {
   89   using ::isblank;
   90 } // namespace std
   91 
   92 #endif // _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_CTYPE_TR1
   93 
   94 #endif // __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
   95 
   96 #endif
```

How can I get isblank() to work? and what are these lines basically about?

**UPDATE**

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch;

    cout << "\n\n\n Enter a character:  ";
    cin >> ch;

    if (isblank(ch))
        cout << "\n blank characters.";

    cout << "\n\n\n";
}
```

code blocks version: 16.01
GCC/G++ compiler and GDB debugger from TDM-GCC (version 4.9.2, 32 bit, SJLJ).

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: See here: [mcve]

Comment: What are your `g++` compile options?  This seems apropos: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958398/gnu-c-how-to-check-when-std-c0x-is-in-effect

Comment: Also, maybe specify your g++ version (run `g++ -dumpversion`) and codeblocks version; this problem seems version-dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK,

Thanks all,

I get it to work by clearing the checked compiler flag:

settings -> compiler settings -> compiler flags -> -std=c++14h

However, I am sure this will affect some other programs. I remember I set this flag because some other features had not worked without it.

Using other compilers is another option as noted in the comments like MinGW64 or MSVC++.

This [link](http://gcc-help.gcc.gnu.narkive.com/prgHdavv/will-gxx-experimental-cxx0x-go-away) could be useful to read:

Thanks again.

Comment: Consider upgrading your compiler, e.g. you can use the latest version of mingw-w64 which does not have the problem.   4.9.2 is quite old now.